# Bit Bang with SPI (fwirte, write performance)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, spi, bitstream

I have a **bit bang** code that allows me to send like 4 megs of data through SPI lines. Its embedded code for custom Hardware using a Linux Kernel.

The problem is that takes a VERY long time to do it (4 hours) this is most likely becase the kernel is doing more stuff. Basically my code is something like this(aprox):

```
unsigned char data=0xFF;

BB_SPI_Init();
SPI_start();//activates chipselect(enable)

for(i=0;i<8;i++){
    if(data & 0x80){
        gpio_set_value(SPI_MOSI,1);
    }else{
        gpio_set_value(SPI_MOSI,0);
    }
    //send pulse clock
    gpio_set_value(SPI_CLK,0);
    gpio_set_value(SPI_CLK,1);
    data<<=1;
}
SPI_stop();//deactivates chipselect(disable)
```

So is a very simple bit bang, but i notice that if i use write to send data to the linux gpio handler `/sys/class/gpio/gpioXX/value` (where XX is any gpio number) it takes 4 hours. 
But if i use `fwrite()` for sending to the same device it takes 3 hours.
BUT, if you use `write()` only for the enables ( `SPI_stop()`, and  SPI_`start()`) and `fwrite()` for sending to MISO, CLK it only takes 1 hour and 30 minutes.

So, with that as a base, could someone explain to me how is that happening? my imagination says that is the way the threads are handled and in every software cycle it resolves 2 threads (`fwrite()` and `write()`) instead if was only one of the functions used, but now i'm still investigating, can someone let me know any kind of information? is there a better way to handle this?

**FYI**
Can't use kernel driver spi because the hardware was connected to gpios and it is a mandatory requirement to use bit bang but i accept any suggestion

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Hey Guys thanks for your comments, it seems that i had a problem (very dumb one) that i created the file descriptor each time that i was going to send data to `sys/class/gpio/gpioxx/value` so that's why was slow. Also turn off some other programs and the transfer skyrocket to 3 minutes instead of 1 hour 30 minutes (with write()). Thanks and Sorry about it

Comment: What's wrong with using spi-bitbang?

Comment: You can find the answer in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20790418/what-are-the-disadvantages-of-bit-banging-spi-i2c-in-embedded-applications?rq=1)  

"Bit-banging carries a software overhead consuming CPU cycles that you could otherwise utilise for other purposes. This may have a noticeable effect on system responsiveness to other events, and in a hard real-time system, may significantly impact the systems ability to meet real-time deadlines."

Comment: Yes, but the alternative is to space each toggle out and take more time overall.

Comment: Yes, but what i need now is to speed up the data transfer for those 4 megs of data, its a firmware update, so it doesnt matter if other tasks suffer

Comment: If it doesn't matter that other tasks suffer, why not use spi-bitbang?

Answer (score 5):

I think that the *spi-bitbang* driver is the best solution if you are looking for performance. Doing the bit-bang from user space is a pain because you have at least 3 system calls for each bit of data. A system call is an expensive operation.

> FYI Can't use kernel driver spi because the hardware was connected to gpios and it is a mandatory requirement to use bit bang but i accept any suggestion

That's why the *spi-bitbang* driver exists. You can easily configure the *spi-bitbang* driver to work with **your** GPIOs.

Then, once you have a *spi-bitbang* driver, you can write a char device that accept as input your entire block of data and transfer it in kernel space. With this solution you will get the maximum performance for a bit-bang interface.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i updated my description saying what was my issue, thanks a lot